# Complexity of built-in methods like list.count(). Do they take O(1) time?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I have two methods to count occurrences of any element. One is using built-in method `count` and other is using loop.
Time complexity for 2nd method is O(n), but not sure of built-in method.
Does `count` take time of `O(1)` or `O(n)`?
Please also tell me about other built-in methods like `reverse`, `index`, etc.
 
Using `count`.

```
List1 = [10,4,5,10,6,4,10]
print(List1.count(10))
```

using loop

```
List2 = [10,4,5,10,6,4,10]
count = 0
for ele in List2:
    if (ele == 10):
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: How would you implement `count` in O(1)?

Comment: No, `.count()` is not O(1).

Comment: *"Please also tell me about other built-in method"*: that makes your question too broad. You should stick to one question.

Comment: @DeepSpace The default List implementation does not keep track of the count of each unique value. However, it would be possible to implement a class that does so and returns the count of an element in O(1)

Comment: Bottom line: You are in for O(n). If you require O(1), you can store the elements in a Default dictionary or even better, create a class with a List and Dict internal data structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

> list.count(x) - Return the number of times x appears in the list.

Now think about it: if you have 10 cups over some coloured balls, can you be 100% certain about the number of red balls under the cups before you check under *all* of the cups?

Hint: No

Therefore, `list.count(x)` has to check the entire list. As the list has size `n`, `list.count(x)` has to be `O(n)`.

EDIT: For the pedantic readers out there, of course there could be an implementation of lists that stores the count of every item. This would lead to an increase in memory usage but would provide the `O(1)` for `list.count(x)`.

EDIT2: You can have a look at the implementation of `list.count` [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5f0fc30de46d41dccf04096df12664fc0a684ca2/Objects/listobject.c#L2560). You will see the for loop that runs exactly `n` times, definitely answering your question: **Built-in methods do not necessarily take `O(1)` time, `list.count(x)` being an example of a built-in method which is `O(n)`**

Comment: List does not implement count in O(1) but I do not agree with your reasoning. It is feasible to implement a List which also keeps track of elements' occurrence.

Comment: Of course it is. I will edit my answer to clarify

Comment: Ok, downvote removed. Oops, I am forced to wait for your edit. Let me know when done.

Comment: No worries. I think it adds clarity to my answer anyway. Thanks for pointing it out. I am trying to look into the source code right now and see how it is implemented.

Comment: ok, all done. Welcome to SO. Where are you from by the way? :-)

Comment: The direct link to the source is a nice touch.  The only way for the loop to terminate early is if the comparison encounters an error, and I don't know how that might happen.

Answer (score 0):

The build in `count()` method in python is also having time complexity of O(n)

The time complexity of the count(value) method is O(n) for a list with n elements. The standard Python implementation cPython “touches” all elements in the original list to check if they are equal to the value. Thus, the time complexity is linear in the number of list elements.

Answer (score -1):

It's an easy thing to see for yourself.

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('x.count(10)', 'x=list(range(100))', number=1000)
0.007884800899773836
>>> timeit.timeit('x.count(10)', 'x=list(range(1000))', number=1000)
0.03378760418854654
>>> timeit.timeit('x.count(10)', 'x=list(range(10000))', number=1000)
0.2234031839761883
>>> timeit.timeit('x.count(10)', 'x=list(range(100000))', number=1000)
2.1812812101561576
```

Maybe a little better than O(n), but definitely closer to that than O(1).